# The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid <= help me

Tags: ios, certificate, cydia

```
**The identity used to sign the executable is no longer valid.** 
Please verify that your device’s clock is properly set, and that your signing certificate is not expired.
```

I've met this error when build my app on iphone by Xcode device for 2 days. It had worked properly before. But only when build on that iphone, the other ios devices is normal, hic. can you help me :(

Comment: Check your iphone date/time in settings. switch it to automatic.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem all of a sudden with my iPad. My date/time settings are correct (automatic), and all of my provisioning profiles are valid and non-expired :(

Comment: Try to fix xcode: https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Fixing-Xcode

Comment: You don't state whether the signing identity is identical and unexpired on all of your devices. Sometimes I update a signing identity but don't pull it down to all devices when I'm developing.

Comment: faced with same problem

Answer (score 2):

You can try to delete the certificates from keychain, restart Xcode and try to download them **(Xcode-Preferences-Accounts-View Details)** and click on **"Download All"**.

If this doesn't work open Xcode accounts **(Xcode-Preferences-Accounts-View Details)** and **right click** on the certificates and **delete** them.
Check in the **member center** if someone is **INACTIVE or EXPIRED** and solve that issue.

The certificates that you manage from the member center are still present even if you delete them from Xcode. Xcode will download all the certificates of the member center.
I had several issues with these certificates, most of the time these operations solved my problems.
Hope it also for you.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen after you renewed your iOS program, even if certificates and provisioning files are not expired yet.

Just edit the provisioning file and re-select the matched certificate.
The certificate you checked for sure before could be unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it enough to force XCode to re-download the certificates. Under XCode -> Preferences... -> Accounts -> your apple id -> View Details, press the reload button in the bottom-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to remove my cert from keychain, then xcode suggested 'fix issue' and everything started working.